# what is the meaning of request succeeds in jquery.post()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I check the ajax $.post() api and see the statement

> A callback function that is executed if the request succeeds

but I don't know what is the meaning of the request succeeds?

I want to do the following:
in jsp post form data to database through java, if save success, then return to jsp and go to next step (is this called request succeeds?),
if fail in the process of saving data to db (for example, some validation of form data failed), then return to jsp and display an error message (is this call request failed).

how to do it?

I see the api has jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), but I don't know what is the .done means?
I need to return something in java to tell this request is success? and return something in java to tell this request is failed?

Comment: An ajax request can fail for numerous reasons from bad connection to incorrect url to server 500 error. Why do you thing there are error handlers?

Answer (score 1):

With success it means whether ajax is able to successfully backend server or not. Definitely, it will not be verifying whether the transaction to the database is successfull or not.

With the call back function it means that you can provide the function, if the response to ajax is 200. Something like code snippet below:

```
var jqxhr = $.post( "example.php", function() {
  // code here
});

jqxhr.success(function() {
  alert( "second finished" );
});
```

But jqxhr.success is depricated in jQuery 3.0 Hence its preferred to do it like below:

```
var jqxhr = $.post( "example.php", function() {
  //code here
})
  .done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
  });
```

Also, once the transaction is complete, you can return it in the response of ajax of whether it was success or not. And then in done call back function you can verify the outcome and accordingly execute the steps for success and failure.

So the final codebase can be something like below:

```
 var jqxhr = $.post( "example.php", function() {
      //code here
    })
      .done(function(data) {
        if(data.result == "success"){
//execute the success code
} else {
//execute the failure code
}
      });
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

> what is the meaning of the request succeeds

There is no error, i.e the status code of the response is 200.

You can either change the status code of the response when a error happen, or just change the response content so you can do wathever you want in your js.

---

Comment: yes, how could I change the response status code in java to make corresponding jqXHR..done(), jqXHR..fail() called?

Comment: You can change it in the HttpServletResponse. 

`public String myController(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
 ...       response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_EXPECTATION_FAILED);//or any other error code.
}`

Comment: I would personnaly, since it's functionnal, send a OK response, but with data that allow me to determine if is was a success or not.